# Calling a function inside a function using export

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function in `test.js` and I am exporting it to reuse in another function.

```js
    function main(data)
    {
    var variable = 123;
    
    function sub()
    {
    console.log(variable);
    console.log(data);
    }
    
    function sub2()
    {
    console.log(variable);
    console.log(data);
    }

    }
    
    
       module.exports ={
            main
        }
```

Then in another js file I am importing like

```js
    var test = require('./test');
```

How do I call the sub or sub2 function? Something like below, also this should have access to **data** and **variable**.

```js
    test.main(data).sub();
```

or if it is easier via class , please let me know how to do via class , thanks.

Comment: `main()` does not return anything, let alone another method.

Comment: I have other stuffs in main , just want to know how to access sub

Comment: You cannot access things that you do not return.  If you create a new method within a method, if you do not return it to the caller, the caller cannot use it.

Answer (score 2):

As Shubh, other suggested you will have to return:

```
function main(data) {
  var variable = 123;

  function sub() {
    console.log(variable);
    console.log(data);
  }

  function sub2() {
    console.log(variable);
    console.log(data);
  }

  return {
    sub,
    sub2
  }
}

main("hello").sub()
```

This is also a kind of classic example of closure.
To make it more obvious:

```
let {sub, sub2} = main("hello")
sub(); // 123, hello
sub2(); // 123, hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .You have to return the inner function ,so that it will form closure and has access to the outer data even though the scope of outer function is over.

```
function main(data)
{
var variable = 123;

return function sub()
{
console.log(variable);
console.log(data);
}

}


   module.exports ={
        main
    }
```

and export it like

```
let {main}=require("./test");
console.log(main("hello")());
```

If you have multiple functions you can try like below

```
function main(data)
{
var variable = 123;

return function sub()
{
console.log(variable);
console.log(data);

return function sub2()
{
console.log("inner",variable);
console.log(data);
}
}

}


   module.exports ={
        main
    }
```

And use it like

```
let {main}=require("./test");
console.log(main("hello")()());
```

Or If you want to call it by their names ,you can use answer suggested by @Ravi

Comment: I have multiple functions like sub

Comment: you can return one function inside other

Comment: I believe she would like to be able to call them in any order she wishes.